# How do I get rid of the dot in the PropertyName of a fluent ValidationResult

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I'm using fluent validation and I've extracted some common validation Rules for email address into a custom email validator eg.

```
public class CustomeEmailValidator  : AbstractValidator<string>
{
    public CustomeEmailValidator (string fieldName)
    {
        RuleFor(m => m).NotEmpty().WithMessage(EmailEmptyMsg).WithName(fieldName);
        RuleFor(m => m).EmailAddress().When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).WithMessage(EmailInvalidMsg).WithName(fieldName);
        RuleFor(m => m).Must(x => x.Length <= 94).When(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).WithMessage(EmailLengthMsg).WithName(fieldName);
    }
}
```

Then call this in other other validators like

```
public class LoginModelValidator : AbstractValidator<LoginModel>
{
    public LoginModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(m => m.Password).NotEmpty().WithMessage(EmptyPasswordMsg);
        RuleFor(m => m.Email).SetValidator(new MediGapEmailValidator("Email"));
    }
}
```

The problem is that the return errors have a error PropertyName of 'Email.Email' or EmailAddress.Email where I need it to be just 'Email' or just a single property name with out the dot.

I've tried OverridePropertyName when calling the setValidator

```
RuleFor(m => m.Email).SetValidator(new MediGapEmailValidator("Email")).OverridePropertyName("Email");
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Is there a better way to factor out this common validation code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try another approach and use extension methods instead of a custom validator. Like this:

```
public static class ValidationExtensions
{
    public static void ValidateEmail<TV>(this AbstractValidator<TV> validator, Expression<Func<TV, string>> property)
    {
        validator.RuleFor(property).NotEmpty().WithMessage(EmailEmptyMsg);
        // other rules go here...
    }
}
```

You can then call this from within any validator:

```
public class UserValidator : AbstractValidator<User>
{
    public UserValidator()
    {
        this.ValidateEmail(x => x.PrimaryEmail);
        this.ValidateEmail(x => x.SecondaryEmail);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should be not the `.OverridePropertyName("Email")` but rather `.OverridePropertyName(string.Empty)`. This way you remove the parent validator part of the path and keep only the child validator part.